# Bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to set of equivalence class

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

If I have an equivalence relation ~ where  $x ∼ y$ if $x = 2^{k}y$ or $y = 2^{k}x$

How would I show that there is a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}/\sim$

where $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ is the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$?

Comment: Where is $k$ supposed to live?

Comment: @wgrenard $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Probably $k\in\mathbb Z$ instead of $k\in\mathbb N$? Because $\sim$ will not be transitive if $k$ is non-negative. For example, $2\sim1$ but $1\nsim2$ because $\nexists k\in\mathbb N$ such that $1=2^k\cdot2$. If $k$ can be negative, then it is fine since $x=2^ky\ \Leftrightarrow\ y=2^{-k}x$

Comment: @MengchunZhang It specifies though that $x \sim y$ if $x = 2^ky$ or $y = 2^kx$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I think this is equivalent to $x \sim y$ if $x = 2^ky$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @wgrenard Good point! I got a mistake about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Any equivalence relation is defined on a certain ground set $X$, e.g., on ${\mathbb R}$. You have not specified such an $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, then the equivalence class of $n$ wrt. $\sim$ is

$$|n| = \{ 2^k n \mid k \geq 0 \}$$

Note that for any odd $n_1, n_2$ where $n_1 \neq n_2$ we have that $|n_1| \cap |n_2| = \emptyset$, so all the equivalence classes generated by odd numbers are pairwise distinct. This shows that there are countably many equivalence classes $C_1, C_2, C_3 \ldots$. In fact, there can be no other equivalence classes.

For if $n$ is even, it is of the form $2^k n_1$, where $n_1$ is odd, and we then have

$$|n| = |n_1|$$.

The desired bijection is therefore $$i \mapsto C_i \text{ for } i \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in\mathbb N$ and let $[x]$ denote the equivalence class of $\sim$ which contains $x$, then 
$$\mathbb N/\sim\ =\ \{\ [0],[n]\mid n=2m+1,\ m\in\mathbb N\ \}.$$
Now, we can construct a bijection$\ \ f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N/\sim$ as the following
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\ \ [0]\ \ \ \,\quad\text{if $\ x=0$}\\ [2x-1]\ \ \ \text{otherwise}\end{matrix}\right..$$